# Loop Through Shapes in a Workbook and rename based on Location

Tags: excel, vba, loops, shapes

I have a macro that adds Text Boxes, and names them `"Fig Num " & ActiveSheet.Shapes.Count`.

Once these text boxes are spread throughout the workbook, I would like to rename all shapes with the name "Fig Num*", or at least the text inside them, to go in order from first worksheet to last, top to bottom, and left to right.

My code renames the text boxes based on seniority. In other words, if I added a text box and it was labeled "Fig Num 3", it would still be named "Fig Num 3" whether it was on the first worksheet or last worksheet.

```vb
Sub Loop_Shape_Name()

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim shp As Shape
Dim i As Integer
Dim Str As String

i = 1

For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

    For Each shp In sht.Shapes
        If InStr(shp.Name, "Fig Num ") > 0 Then                              
            sht.Activate
            shp.Select
            shp.Name = "Fig Num"
        End If
    Next shp
     
    For Each shp In sht.Shapes
        If InStr(shp.Name, "Fig Num") > 0 Then
            sht.Activate
            shp.Select
            shp.Name = "Fig Num " & i
            Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = _
              "FIG " & i
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next shp
        
Next sht
End Sub
```

I found code that will do what I'm looking for, however it's a bit clunky. I also need a good way to find the last row on the sheet that contains a shape. Since the shape names are based on creation, if I insert a shape in row 35 and use the `Shape.Count` featured below, it will skip all shapes after row 35 unless I add additional rows that bog down the code.

Most recent code (loops through grouped shapes):

```vb
Private Sub Rename_FigNum2()
 
'Dimension variables and data types
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim shp As Shape
Dim subshp As Shape
Dim i As Integer
Dim str As String
Dim row As Long
Dim col As Long
Dim NextRow As Long
Dim NextRow1 As Long
Dim NextCol As Long
Dim rangex As Range
Dim LR As Long

i = 1

'Iterate through all worksheets in active workbook
For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If sht.Visible = xlSheetVisible Then
        LR = Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).row + 200
    
        If sht.Shapes.Count > 0 Then
            With sht
                NextRow1 = .Shapes(.Shapes.Count).BottomRightCell.row + 200
                'NextCol = .Shapes(.Shapes.Count).BottomRightCell.Column + 10
            End With
    
            If LR > NextRow1 Then
                NextRow = LR
            Else
                NextRow = NextRow1
            End If
        End If

        NextCol = 15
     
        Set rangex = sht.Range("A1", sht.Cells(NextRow, NextCol))
    
        For row = 1 To rangex.Rows.Count
            For col = 1 To rangex.Columns.Count
   
                For Each shp In sht.Shapes
                    If shp.Type = msoGroup Then
                        For Each subshp In shp.GroupItems
                            If Not Intersect(sht.Cells(row, col), subshp.TopLeftCell) Is Nothing Then
                                If InStr(subshp.Name, "Fig Num") > 0 Then
                                    subshp.Name = "Fig Num " & i
                                    subshp.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = _
                                      "FIG " & i
                                    i = i + 1
                                End If
                            End If
                        Next subshp 
            
                    Else
                        If Not Intersect(sht.Cells(row, col), shp.TopLeftCell) Is Nothing Then
                            If InStr(shp.Name, "Fig Num ") > 0 Then
                                shp.Name = "Fig Num " & i
                                shp.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = _
                                  "FIG " & i
                                i = i + 1
                            End If
                        End If
                        
                    End If
                Next shp
                
            Next col
        Next row
    End If
    
Next sht

End Sub
```

Example of Workbook:
[image: Example of Workbook]

Comment: When you say 'page' do you mean 'worksheet'?

Comment: Yes, worksheet would be more correct. This is eventually printed to PDF where the "page" descriptor originated from.

Answer (score 0):

### Rename Text Boxes

- To use the `ArrayList`, you have to have [`.NET Framework 3.5 SP1`](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-framework/net35-sp1) installed, even if you already have a later version (e.g. `4.7`) installed.
- It is assumed that each text box is an `ActiveX` control (not a `Form` control) and has a (per worksheet) unique top-left cell.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub RenameTextBoxes()
    
    Const oTypeName As String = "TextBox" ' OLEObject Type Name
    Const fPattern As String = "Fig Num " ' Find Pattern (Unsorted)
    Const tPattern As String = "Dummy" ' Temporary Pattern
    Const nPattern As String = "Fig Num " ' New Pattern (Sorted)
    Const ByRows As Boolean = False
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim arl As Object: Set arl = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim ole As OLEObject
    Dim Key As Variant
    Dim n As Long
    Dim r As Long
    Dim Coord As Double
    Dim tName As String
    
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        
        arl.Clear
        dict.RemoveAll
        
        For Each ole In ws.OLEObjects
            If TypeName(ole.Object) = oTypeName Then
                If InStr(1, ole.Name, fPattern, vbTextCompare) = 1 Then
                    n = n + 1
                    If ByRows Then
                        Coord = GetNumericByRows(ole.TopLeftCell)
                    Else
                        Coord = GetNumericByColumns(ole.TopLeftCell)
                    End If
                    arl.Add Coord
                    tName = tPattern & n
                    ole.Name = tName
                    dict(Coord) = tName
                End If
            End If
        Next ole
        
        arl.Sort
        
        For Each Key In arl
            r = r + 1
            ws.OLEObjects(dict(Key)).Name = nPattern & r
            'Debug.Print nPattern & r, Key, dict(Key)
        Next Key
    
    Next ws
    
End Sub


Function GetNumericByColumns( _
    ByVal OneCellRange As Range) _
As Double
    If OneCellRange Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    With OneCellRange.Cells(1)
        GetNumericByColumns = Val(.Column & "." & Format(.Row, "000000#"))
    End With
End Function

Function GetNumericByRows( _
    ByVal OneCellRange As Range) _
As Double
    If OneCellRange Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    With OneCellRange.Cells(1)
        GetNumericByRows = Val(.Row & "." & Format(.Column, "0000#"))
    End With
End Function


' Modify the range address to see what the 'GetNumeric' functions are all about.
Sub GetNumericTEST()
    Dim cCell As Range: Set cCell = Sheet1.Range("XFD1048576")
    Debug.Print GetNumericByColumns(cCell)
    Debug.Print GetNumericByRows(cCell)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, VBasic. I ran the code and unfortunately it did nothing. I believe this is because the text boxes are not ActiveX. They are an inserted shape. *Sorry, still new to all of this, so sorry if that doesn't make sense. Is there a way to get the numeric row coordinates based off the inserted shapes?

Comment: No problem. You have answered your own question. Still, you have been presented with an idea which you could apply to your case. Your shapes are ordered by rows so you only need the `GetNumericByRows` function modified where you could stick with `TopLeftCell` or, as another idea, you could use the `Top` and `Left` of the shapes multiplied by `100` to get rid of the decimals, and use the `Top` as the integer part and use the `Left` as the decimal part with `7` decimals (`000000#`). Sorry, but I'm not sure that I'll have the time to look into it, certainly not today.

Comment: Not sure, but it may be as easy as the following: change to `Const ByRows As Boolean = True`, replace `ole` with `shp`, `OLEObjects` with `Shapes`, and get rid of the line `If TypeName(ole.Object) = oTypeName Then` and its corresponding `End If`. Of course, this will only change the shape names, but it's a start. Then in the last loop do your 'TextFrame' and the 'cell-replace' part.